# No "connect" button in the windows 8 network menu

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

In windows 8 (64bit) I can't connect to a new wireless network. I can find them but when I click on a particular network the "connect" button does not appear. It used to work, so I have no idea what's wrong. If I try to "Set up a new connection" via the "Network and sharing center" no wireless networks show up at all. Wired connections still work fine. My computer is about half a year old ASUS S400C.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should reinstall the network drivers for windows 8.
Use this link:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=21642

Comment: Just a friendly suggestiong, we try not to use direct links like these too often because in a year or so, it could be dead.

Comment: Thanks but the wireless network adapter is Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG. I reinstalled the corresponding driver but the problem is still there.